# How can I move docker volume from specific folder to general docker structure

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose I have a following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4.2
    ports:
    - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-volume:/data/db
```

And now I want to move that volume, so I could use the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4.2
    ports:
    - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongvol:/data/db
volumes:
  mongvol:
```

Comment: This is basically the same case as "Restore container from backup", in the Docker [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#restore-container-from-backup) documentation.

Comment: docker documentation contains only a way to backup volume without folder specified

Comment: You already have the contents that you need, though: they're in the `mongo-volume` subdirectory.  So you need to create the named volume and copy it in.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I assume you would like to start the docker volume and point it to your local ./mongo-volume. You can try to start up a docker volume as follows

```
docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=none \
      --opt device=<your-folder-path-here> \
      --opt o=bind \
      test_vol
```

Comment: actually I want to get rid of the local folder mongo-volume

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
docker container create --name temp -v mongovall:/data busybox
cd mongo-volume
docker cp . temp:/data
docker rm temp
```

than change docker compose as follows:

```
 volumes:
      - mongovall:/data/db
volumes:
  mongovall:
    external: true
```